# Why Do we have TwoPlusArrayList and OnePlusArrayList inside Lists class?

Tags: java, guava

I am just curious about the Lists class implementation of google guava, we have two methods to create List from Array,

```
Lists.asList(E first, E[] rest)
Lists.asList(E first, E second, E[] rest)
```

Why do these methods has first and rest separately? cant it be like Arrays.asList implementation of java ?

The only thing I am able to see is the first and second is nullable and rest is not nullable

Can anyone help to understand this ?

Comment: If I have two individual elements and an array of the remaining elements, how would I use Arrays.asList?

Comment: If we don't have any individual element and have only an Array then I have no other option than passing null.

Comment: Arrays.asList is the reverse procedure of Lists.asList

Comment: If you don't have any individual elements, then you have a different problem to what this method solves. My question is if you *do* have two individual elements and an array, how would you make a list of them? The answer is that you would use this convenience method.

Comment: Normally libraries doesn't solves such specific cases, if this is the case then three parameter and array is also a valid case.

Comment: Normally third-party libraries don't simply duplicate the same behaviour as the standard library; what would be the point if `Lists.asList` was just like `Arrays.asList`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the job of the Lists.asList() is not exactly to directly convert an array to a list.

> Suppose we have an array, and we want to insert an element to it, we can’t do it as the array size is fixed. One solution to this problem is to allocate an new array of +1 the size of the original array and copy all elements from the original array to the new array. This works but it is highly inefficient.
>
> Guava provides an efficent solution to this problem – Guava’s `Lists.asList()` method returns an unmodifiable list backed by the original array which also contains the specified element.

source: https://www.techiedelight.com/guava-lists-class-java/

So basically, you can use it to just convert an array by giving the first and/or second parameters (depending upon what method you are using) as null, and giving the "rest" parameter as your array.

This will return your array as list, perhaps with null as the first index (and second as well, depending on what you are using)

But if you want, you can use the same methods to get a list with some specific data appended to your array (at first and second index values)

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Note that giving the first element as null does not mean the list would just hold the remaining elements. In fact, the list would contain the first element regardless - a null element in this case. If you want to create a list from an array only, then just use Arrays.asList.

Comment: After some analysis I think they are trying to enforce atleast one or two parameter in the List,

Answer (score 1):

The main reason these methods exist is to help you when you write a method with a signature like

```java
void foo(Bar first, Bar... rest);
```

which is something you'd do when you want to allow the user to call the method as if it were a method with just a varargs parameter, but you want to require that it be called with a minimum of one or two arguments (whereas varargs alone would allow them to call it with zero). In the implementation of such a method, you might want to treat those arguments as a single list. `Lists.asList` does that without doing any array copying:

```java
void foo(Bar first, Bar... rest) {
  List<Bar> bars = Lists.asList(first, rest);
  // ...
}
```